# How far into our galaxy did the Doomsday Machine get?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

The theory was that the planet killing *Doomsday Machine* was built by a long-gone civilization from another galaxy for use during an unknown war. It was on course to the heart of our galaxy when the Enterprise encountered it and the battle damaged USS Constellation after following its wake of destruction through two star systems.

Where in the Star Trek galaxy did the encounter with the Doomsday Machine take place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The Constellation was destroyed in the Rigel system, Kandari sector, Alpha Quadrant.** Specifically in a nearby star system called L-374. So depending on the vector (and assuming the weapon was coming from the edge of the galaxy closest to us) it would not have traveled a great distance into our galaxy. Or perhaps it only destroyed things directly in its path. I can see a lot of stars from the edge of the galaxy before it reached Sol...

[image]

> The Rigel system was an inhabited planetary system consisting of at least twelve planets around its primary Rigel. An asteroid field was located 2 days away at impulse speed from Rigel XII. (TOS: "Mudd's Women", "The Doomsday Machine"; ENT: "Broken Bow")
>
> The Rigel system was the first star system visited by the Enterprise NX-01, the first Earth starship with the warp 5 engine, after it departed from the Sol system. The Rigel colony on Rigel X was a popular trade complex at the time, visited by numerous species. (ENT: "Broken Bow")

In the mid-23rd century, the Rigel system was part of the most densely populated section of the Milky Way Galaxy. (TOS: "The Doomsday Machine")

Comment: I thought L-374, where Constellation was destroyed, was _[near](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Constellation_(NCC-1017))_ the 'Rigel' system(note, [not](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=75275) analogous to real-life placements).

Comment: Yes, early Star Trek played very loosey-goosey with where their stars and planets were placed in relationship to Earth. Those stars, planets and systems which show up on a map like the one above do not indicate EVERY star in the vicinity, only the important ones. And no, they are not always where they should be on a REAL star map...

Comment: I suppose not.  Good find with the map, though.

Answer (score 5):

[L-374](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/System_L-374), near the previously-dominated [L-370](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/L-370_system) system, and the [Rigel System](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rigel_system).

You asked where in the 'Star Trek Galaxy'.  If you're trying to map this upon our current understanding of the Milky Way Galaxy, [good luck](http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=75275).